# Silhouette a human body image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to convert the **Image A** to **Image B** using Matlab. I'm new to Matlab and didn't find good source of doing it. can anyone help me in this matter?

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

The horizontal lines in the Image B can be ignored. I just want to get the body shape as in Image B

Comment: Canny edge detector might help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector

Comment: search `edge detection` and you will get lot of methods.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to convert the source image to binary and subtract an eroded copy like this:

```
bw = any(I, 3);
n = 5;
s = bw - bwmorph(bw, 'erode', n);
```

Varying the value of `n` will change the thickness of the outline in the final image.

Comment: You can use `bwmorph(bw,'remove')` to get the silhouette.